# MAVEN How to add a common library in many modules without increasing ear size?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module

I have a maven ear with many moduls that require the same dependencies.

To avoid repeat the same dependencies in every module I add it on ear and I had no problems on production environment.

The problem comes when I have to test in local with IntelliJ, because a current module does not have that dependency.

Should I create a lib maven module to get all duplicated dependencies in one place and add this lib module to all modules that need them? Does this dependency increase the ear size?

**Initial state**

```
app
 - app-ear
 - app-back
   -poi
 - app-front
   -poi
```

**Current state**

```
app
 - app-ear
   - poi
 - app-back
 - app-front
```

**Possible solution** this would be a good solution

```
app
 - app-ear
 - app-lib
   - poi
 - app-back
   -app-lib
 - app-front
   -app-lib
```

Comment: Usually, you add to every module the dependencies that are needed by that particular module. If all of your modules need the same five dependencies, you might create a particular module of packaging POM that lists these dependencies. Then you can use it as dependency in the modules.

Comment: Do you mean https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/skinny-modules.html ?